# Database/Server setting about sorting - PostgreSQL 10/11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-order.html

When you do sorting in Postgres you can specify if NULLs should come first or last. You can do this in every ORDER BY clause.

But... I wonder if there's a setting for this on the DB level, or on the server level... so that you don't need to specify always `NULLS FIRST` if that's what you **always** want for ASC sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

The default value for `ASC` ordering is always `NULLS LAST`, and for `DESC` it is `NULLS FIRST`. If you need anything else, you'll have to say it explicitly.

Comment: Strange... I thought there would be some DB level or sever level setting. Anyway, OK... thank you.